# Como add dois valores dentro de um v-select?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuetify

Ex:

```
let caracteristica = {
  id_caracteristica: 2,
  caracteristicas: "exCaracteristica"
}

<v-flex xs12 sm3 md6>
  <v-select
    v-model="selectdCaracteristica"
    label="Caracteristicas"
    :items="caracteristica"
    item-text="caracteristicas"
    item-value="caracteristicas"
  ></v-select>
</v-flex>
```

onde eu encaixaria o id_caracteristica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu `items` deveria ser um array contendo os valores que serão exibidos na listagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Can be an array of objects or array of strings. When using objects, will look for a text and value field. This can be changed using the item-text and item-value props. Objects that have a header or divider property are considered special cases and generate a list header or divider; these items are not selectable.

---

Traduzindo:

> Pode ser um array de objetos ou array de strings. Ao usar objetos,
>   procurará um campo de texto e valor. Isso pode ser alterado usando as propriedade item-text e item-value. Objetos que possuam uma
>   propriedade de cabeçalho ou divisor são considerados casos especiais e
>   geram um cabeçalho ou divisor de lista; esses itens não são
>   selecionáveis.

Perceba que eu coloquei dentro de `[]`, você pode colocar mais items chamando o método `.push()` com o novo objeto.

```
let caracteristica = [{
  id_caracteristica: 2,
  caracteristicas: "exCaracteristica"
}]

<v-flex xs12 sm3 md6>
  <v-select
    v-model="selectdCaracteristica"
    label="Caracteristicas"
    :items="caracteristica"
    item-text="caracteristicas"
    item-value="caracteristicas"
  ></v-select>
</v-flex>
```

Talvez você possa usar o `id_caracteristica` no `item-value`, dessa forma o valor da propriedade seria usada no no `v-model`